# embedded swf auto-zoomed when loaded

Tags: html, flash

I am embedding swf videos of size 1280x800 into an html document, and am trying to scale them down to 800x500.  The problem is they are scaling down, but showing at the original size - zoomed in.  So in order to see them properly, I have to right click -> show all.

```
<object style="width: 800px; height: 500px;" width="800" height="500" data="video.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="data" value="video.swf" />
<param name="scale" value="exactfit" />
<param name="src" value="video.swf" />
</object>
```

I also tried a simpler version:

```
<object width="800" height="500">
<param name="movie" value="video.swf">
</object>
```

but again, the flash is zoomed in when the page loads.

Is there a better way to scale them, or a way to fix the zoom-in issue?

Answer (score 0):

depends on the swf file. some scale down, some dont.

afaik theres no way to influence this by embedding options.

there are however workarounds. in javascript for example.

you should alys try using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) for embedding, to be sure everything is done correctly. it also takes care of browser differences etc for you.